# Is it possible to disable communications on a mobile phone with software?

Tags: mobile

Is it possible to disable all communications on a mobile phone (on any brand, like blackberry, iphone or android phone, or even an mp3 player like an ipod) this includes incoming/outgoing calls and text messages, and internet use - for a period of time like an hour or two?

In some way that can't easily be bypassed - like closing the app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that most mp3 players already come with all communication options disabled ...

Comment: Yes, but some like the iPod can use the internet over wifi. Anyway to disable that - temporarily?

Comment: For the iPhone 4, I think you just need to grip it firmly with your left hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take out a SIM card out of a phone that uses them and there is no WiFi network around that should just about do it. Or you can use a phone that doesn't have WiFi (certain older Blackberries I think).

Alternatively something like the iPod Touch in a room without a WiFi network would also do it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be cumbersome, but on a BB device you can likely inject keyboard events in order to turn off the radio.  I don't know of a way to use straightforward APIs to disable the radio.

Not sure if this is your goal but you can programatically manipulate the inbox.  If a new message arrives while you're "disabled" you can delete it from the inbox.